# Pattern matching in sql failed, datetime conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am receiving a Code in sms like "yyyy/mm-digit" (digit increments with every message). so i want to ensure that the code sent by user is exactly in that format otherwise another action. So how ?

Here is my code to check but it always execute else block, why ? Note: I want it for e.g. "2014/8-digit" kinda pattern , how ? (it changes with respect to year and month)

Here is my little effort but it's throwing dateitme conversion failed error plus it might have other issues too, Help

```
Alter PROCEDURE TestTrigger



AS
BEGIN
     Begin Try
           Declare @msg as varchar(20)
           SELECT @msg = '2014/9-1'

           DECLARE @yyyymm varchar(255) = Convert(Varchar ,(cast(year(@msg) as varchar(255)) + '/' +
                                right(cast(month(@msg) as varchar(255)), 2)
                               ));

                IF (@msg like @yyyymm + '-[0-9]%' and
                    @msg not like @yyyymm + '-%[^0-9]%'
                   )
                  BEGIN
                    Print 'Done'
                  END
                  ELSE
                  BEGIN
                    Print 'Not Done'
                  END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
     Select ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMsg
    END CATCH

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You have missed '0' on the day field. Please see below:
Before it was : '2014/9-2'
Correction to SELECT @msg = '2014/09-2'

Full solution is described below :

```
 Declare @msg as varchar(20)
           SELECT @msg = '2014/09-2'

           DECLARE @yyyymm varchar(255) = (cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(255)) + '/' +
                                right('00' + cast(month(getdate()) as varchar(255)), 2)
                               );



                IF (@msg like @yyyymm + '-[0-9]%' and
                    @msg not like @yyyymm + '-%[^0-9]%'
                   )
                  BEGIN
                    Print 'Done'
                  END
                  ELSE
                  BEGIN
                    Print 'Not Done'
                  END
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which means you setting
SELECT @msg = '2014/8-2'. Try to change it to
SELECT @msg = '2014/08-2', you need to append '0' before 8 because @yyyymm is coming as '2014-08'.